# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo - how to convert a column data type to sql represenation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, smo

If I am using SQL Server Management objects, and I have a instance of a column object, and I want to generate a T-SQL script from it,  how do I best convert the column data type to how it should be represented in SQL?

The [Column class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.column?view=sql-smo-140.17283.0) has properties such as:

- SQL Server data type (VarChar, VarBinary, XML, etc)
- NumericPrecision
- NumericScale
- IsPrecise
- MaxLength
- IsNumericType
- IsStringType

I'm finding it a bit challenging to look at the properties and render out the correct text to for a T-SQL script. `DateTimeOffset`, `DateTime`, `Float` and `Int` are good examples. They all have precision and scale and max length values but the format for the rendered data type is quite different.

Is there a function in the SMO library to do this form me?

Examples:

```
Type                IsNumericType   IsStringType    Precision   Scale   MaxLength   Rendered result
bigint              TRUE            FALSE           19          0       8           BigInt
bit                 FALSE           FALSE           1           0       1           Bit
char                FALSE           TRUE            0           0       10          Char(10)
datetime            FALSE           FALSE           23          3       8           DateTime
datetimeoffset      FALSE           FALSE           34          7       10          DateTimeOffset(7)
decimal             TRUE            FALSE           10          3       9           Decimal(10,3)
float               TRUE            FALSE           53          0       8           float
int                 TRUE            FALSE           10          0       4           int
uniqueidentifier    FALSE           FALSE           0           0       16          uniqueidentifier
varchar             FALSE           TRUE            0           0       10          VarChar(10)
varchar             FALSE           TRUE            0           0       -1          VarChar(MAX)
varbinary           FALSE           FALSE           0           0       10          VarBinary(10)
varbinary           FALSE           FALSE           0           0       -1          VarBinary(MAX)
xml                 FALSE           FALSE           0           0       -1          XML
```

Comment: is `Column`.`DataType`.`SqlDataType` not sufficient for your purposes? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.sqldatatype

Comment: No, that is purely an enum, so it doesn't express length, scale, precision, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the SMO library that does this exact thing, unfortunately it's not a public method.

Therefore, the simplest way is to do it via reflection:

```
var getTypeDefinitionScriptMethod = typeof(UserDefinedDataType).GetMethod("GetTypeDefinitionScript", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var declaration = getTypeDefinitionScriptMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {new ScriptMaker().Preferences, column, "DataType", false}) as string;
```

The value of "declaration" after this code will be the full datatype, for example "nvarchar(max)", "decimal(18,0)", "int", etc.